# Using RelativeLayout to make a View take all remaining space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to achieve this


[image: required]

I am doing this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/upper"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/wallet_dim_foreground_inverse_disabled_holo_dark">
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/upper"
        android:background="@color/blueAccentColor">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/upper"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lower"
        android:background="@color/wallet_dim_foreground_inverse_disabled_holo_dark">
        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lower"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/blueAccentColor"></LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the first Layout to be above the seconde.

With the code you provided you will have a top layout taking all space, and a bottom layout being below him. If you think about it you can see that it's logic that the result will be different.

If you remove `android:layout_below="@+id/upper"`and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`from the lower one, this Layout will be anchored to the bottom side, whichever the screen size is.

Than adding `android:layout_above="@+id/lower"` to the top Layout, he will take all space(thanks to `android:layout_height="fill_parent"`) but it will stay above the lower Layout.

Here is the result you want :)